# How to parse json file

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a problem with parsing

my json file:

```json
[{
    "username": "abc",
    "number": "1",
    "Coordinates": "3479087.7179635554,4723293.992024612,3587934.046241646,4936094.678770542"
 },
 {
    "username": "ab",
    "number": "2",
    "Coordinates": "3638076.736796722,4693942.173163104,3669874.540563355,4955662.558011548"
}]
```

modal:

```
namespace WebUygAPI.Models
{
    public class DrawInfo
    {
        public string username { get; set; } 
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string coordinates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having in the controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetDraws")]
public async Task<IActionResult> get()
{
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Casper\source\repos\WebUygAPI\WebUygAPI\LineData.json";
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string o1 = file.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

When I'm debugging I can see json file in `o1` but I couldn't parse it.

I tried to parse but I had errors such as

> newtonsoft.json.jsonreaderexception: unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Comment: Where is your code parsing it?

Comment: _"but i had errors such as"_ Please include exact errors messages.

Comment: There's no code shown which attempts to parse the JSON data or would produce the error described.  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry i'm very new. I have the problem fixed from an answer. I'll look into how to ask better questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

List<DrawInfo> info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DrawInfo>>(json);
```